# ESlint rule for function names with TypeScript (camelCase with lower case for first letter)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint

Following [these](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style) guidelines (and almost any other), `function`s and `var` names should use lowerCamelCase while `Class` (and c'tors) names should use UpperCamelCase.

I've looked for an `ESLint` rule to enforce this convention but the closest I've found is [id-match](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/id-match) which doesn't seem to distinguish between `function`, `var`, or `class`.

Is there a better rule? Should I be using the `id-match` rule along with [new-cap](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap) rule? (feels dirty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems like there is no better option at the moment...

> Unfortunately, it looks like there wasn't enough interest from the team
>   or community to implement this change. While we wish we'd be able to
>   accommodate everyone's requests, we do need to prioritize. We've found
>   that issues failing to reach accepted status after 21 days tend to
>   never be accepted, and as such, we close those issues.
>   This doesn't mean the idea isn't interesting or useful, just that it's
>   not something the team can commit to.
>   https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/10473